# django-nonrel performance on Google App Engine

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

What is the performance impact of developing applications on Google App Engine using django-nonrel as opposed to webapp?

I am aware that there is not much difference between webapp and the django which is included in google appengine already, but the question is more around the fine work the guys have been doing over at : http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django imposes a fairly significant startup overhead over lighter weight frameworks like Webapp (which only use parts of Django, optionally) - anything up to an additional 500 milliseconds if you believe the benchmarks. This can be alleviated or eliminated with [warmup requests](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Warmup_Requests) and [always on instances](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Always_On).

After startup, I wouldn't expect a significant difference in efficiency - most of the time spent is going to be waiting for RPCs in any framework - but you may find these [benchmarks of template and framework performance](http://www.untilnil.com/2010/08/appenginetemplate4/) interesting.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Does this mean that the first time the application is hit, there is a 500 millisecond wait?

Comment: @user791793 Unless you're using always on instances, or the infrastructure sent a warmup request to the app first, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Django is not included with appengine, appengine just uses the django templating library. Webapp is another framework which is derived from [webob](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/do-it-yourself.html). Coming to django-nonrel

`Django-nonrel is a project which allows developers to run native Django projects (including Django's ORM) on non-relational databases, one of which is Google App Engine's Datastore. (This is all in addition to the standard traditional SQL databases that have always been supported by Django.) App Engine does come with some Django support, but this is mainly only the templating and views. Other tools that allow for rapid development such as forms, the built-in administration interface or Django authentication just won't run out-of-the-box. Django-nonrel changes this for Django developers.`

Django-nonrel mainly is for running your current django projects on appengine without much efforts. coming to performance impact, i don't think there will be much of impact on performance while opting for django-nonrel.

Comment: Django *is* included in app engine -- just not all of it can be used as is.  See here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django . In addition, as far as I can tell, the only relevant part of this is "i don't think there will be much of impact on performance while opting for django-nonrel." Do you have anything to back this up, one way or the other?  Any qualifications on this?